Set Theory: Proof that the number of elements in a set does not depends by counting order
I'm approaching the Set Theory, studying the axioms provided by the Zermelo–Fraenkel.
I wondered if there is a way to prove that the number of elements in a set does not depend on the order followed to count them.
I am referring to the fact that, for example, if a set has cardinality 3 then it means that it is possible to establish a bijection between the set and the set 3 (defined as the set having objects (0,1,2)). Intuitively I know that, if I can establish a bijective function between the sets, then I can do it with any choice of element pairs coming from the two sets. So the cardinality is independent of the order followed for the counting. In other words, it is not possible to count the elements of a set twice and obtain a different result.
Is this fact an axiom embedded in the definition of cardinality or can it be proved?
When I asked Chat GPT if there were any proofs in the literature, he replied that the definition of cardinality of a set, together with the Extensionality axiom, include the fact that the number of elements in a set does not depend on the order followed to count them.
I honestly don't have much faith in Chat GPT. But I didn't find anything in my book.
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

How do you define cardinality? In set theory a set of cardinality $3$ is often defined to be a set that has a bijection with the set $3$.

I think, it should be enough to prove that a finite set cannot be in bijection with its proper part. A proof by induction may work...

@Mark, I believe to understand that the question is about showing that cardinality is well-defined and does not depend on the choice of bijection. I think this fact is often skipped as obvious, even in a kindergarten, but it is not obvious.

@Alexey Oh, that of course. It has to be shown that if $m\ne n$ then there is no bijection between the sets $m$ and $n$. But this is a standard result, and the proof appears in many places.

@Mark yes i agree with that definition.

@Alexey yes, you get the point. As you say, it seems an obvius fact, but I realized I can't find a way to analitically proof it. So comes the question: is reallly possibile to prrof it or is an axiom? May it derive from the Zermelo–Fraenkel axioms?

ValerioQuattrini, the axioms of ZF are well known, this is not a part of them. @Mark says this is a standard result. I also do not think this could be hard to prove. But I think we get to a point in mathematical reasoning where we need to get clear what is understood by a proof. What level of formalism do you want? Do you want to use a formal proof system, like Natural Deduction or Sequent Calculus?

@Alexey It's hard for me to choose a way to proof something when I don't know how to do it. I wonder the reason why there is no much literature about the question. My impression is that the formalism of set theory, starting from the abstract definition of cardinality, respects the result we are talking about and includes it in its definitions because it cannot prove it. For this reason the results obtained respect the expected one, that is, that the number of elements in a set does not depend on the order in which they are counted. Unfortunately I have no other material to rely on.

The problem here is not how to prove something, it's how to even state what you want to prove. Your question doesn't make sense unless you can formulate it in precise mathematical language.

@NaïmFavier, the question is fairly precise: prove that the cardinality of a finite set is well defined, where by the cardinality of a finite set $A$ we mean the natural (ordinal) number $n$, such that there is a bijection between $A$ and ${0,,1,,\dotsc,,n-1}$.

@ValerioQuattrini, I am pretty sure that all the results in ZF set theory can be deduced from axioms completely formally. You may be interested in checking out some literature on Proof Theory, such as Basic Proof Theory by Troelstra and Schwichtenberg. You may also be interested in learning about proof assistant software which allow to formalize a variety of mathematical reasoning.

Thank you @Alexey. Ainway, you perfectly understood my question. Sorry if my description was not better formulated.

For those who do not find the question precise enough, here is a formalisation of its essence: $(\forall m\in\omega)(\forall n\in\omega)(\forall f\colon n\to m)(\forall g\colon m\to n)(g\text{ is two-sided inverse of }f\ \Rightarrow\ m = n)$.  I suppose that a proof in Sequent Calculus using only the axioms of ZF will suffice as an answer.

I posted my version of this question.

I am trying to rapidly create a proof, I hope the result will be accurate enough so that all holes in it could be filled in.
You want to prove that if a set $A$ is in bijection with two standard finite ordinals $m =\{0,\,1,\dotsc,\,m - 1\}$ and $n =\{0,\,1,\dotsc,\,n - 1\}$, then $m = n$.
It is enough to prove that if $m$ and $n$ are two distinct finite ordinals, then there is no bijection between them.
Proof by reduction to absurd (or by induction).
Suppose two distinct finite ordinals $m =\{0,\,1,\dotsc,\,m - 1\}$ and $n =\{0,\,1,\dotsc,\,n - 1\}$ are in bijection, and $m < n$.
Without loss of generality, assume that $n$ is the least finite ordinal that is in bijection with a strictly smaller one (strictly smaller means strictly preceding in the sense of order, not smaller in the sense of cardinality, which is yet to be defined).
Let $f\colon n\to m$ be such a bijection.
We can incidentally observe that $m$ is non-empty, because $f(n-1)\in m$.
In particular, $m - 1$ is defined.
Let us construct a bijection $g\colon (n - 1)\to(m - 1)$ and thus obtain a contradiction with the minimality of $n$.
Here it is:
$$
g(x) =\begin{cases}
f(x)
&\text{if}\
f(x) < f(n-1),\\
f(x) - 1
&\text{if}\
f(x) > f(n-1).
\end{cases}
$$
I think this works and can be written completely formally.
If I recall correctly, in general, a cardinal is defined as an ordinal that is not in bijection with any strictly preceding one.
The above argument shows that finite ordinals are all cardinals.

I have trouble mentally visualizing the g function, but I think we're on the right track.

@ValerioQuattrini, you "remove" the top element from $n$, then its image in $m$ becomes "unused". So, you redefine the part of $f$ that produces images above the unused element to use it, and "unuse" the top element of $m$ instead.  (You may draw a schema for $f$ and see what $g$ does.)

@ValerioQuattrini, by the way, you can upvote the unswer if you like :).

So should not the ">" symbol in the g function definition to be an equality instead?

@ValerioQuattrini, no, why? If $f(x) = f(n-1)$, then $x = n - 1$ and "$g(x)$" is not defined.

I would pay for a draw :))

@ValerioQuattrini, unfortunately, as this is a part of a proof that the bijection $n\to m$ does not exist, it does not exist, and cannot be drawn. But you can draw an analogous construction where we start from a bijection $f\colon n\to n$, and obtain a bijection $g\colon (n-1)\to (n-1)$ by the same formula. Just draw two sets of, say, 7 points each, representing numbers from $0$ to $6$, draw arrows from one set to the other to represent a bijection $f\colon 7\to 7$, and then draw (in another color) arrows representing the corresponding $g\colon 6\to 6$.

Perfect, the part I can't figure out is to visualize f(x)-1 when f(x)>f(n−1). How can f(x) be greather than f(n-1) if n-1 is the top?

@ValerioQuattrini, hm... Say, you had $(f(0),f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5),f(6)) = (6,1,3,5,2,0,4)$ (so, $f(6) = 4$). Then $(g(0),g(1),g(2),g(3),g(4),g(5)) = (5,1,3,4,2,0)$. Draw this.

Ok done, so the g function seems to not define a mapping for element "6".

@ValerioQuattrini, that's the point of defining $g$. To get a contradiction with the minimality of $n$.

So we proofd that if we remove the top element from the set n, we lose an arrow pointing to m. So there is an element left free in m. But n > m so it can't be. Thats the reasoning?

@ValerioQuattrini, please read carefully: we assumed that $n$ was the least ordinal in bijection with a strictly smaller one, and we concluded that $n - 1$ is also in bijection with a strictly smaller one.

You can do something like the following: Suppose that $X$ is a set with at least two distinct elements, $a, b$. If $Y$ is a set and $f: X \to Y$ is a bijection then the new function $$g(x) = \begin{cases} f(b), &\text{ if } x = a\\f(a), &\text{ if } x = b\\f(x), &\text{ if } x \ne a,b \end{cases}$$ is also a bijection, but swaps the images of $a$ and $b$. Thus, you have reordered (a part of) the bijection.
Of course, for infinite sets you have to be careful. While you can still swap any two (and thus any finite set)  however you want and preserve your bijection, this will not always work for every reordering for infinite subsets -- the identity is clearly a bijection from $\mathbb{W} = \{0,1,2,...\}$ to itself. If we continually swap the image of $0$ and $1$, and then $0$ and $2$, and then $0$ and $3$, ... we'll find that we have created $f(n) = n+1$ which is no longer a bijection.

How can any of this be used to prove that there is no bijection between $m ={0,,1,\dotsc,,m - 1}$ and $n ={0,,1,\dotsc,,n - 1}$ when $m\ne n$?  This is the question.
